# How to save list workflow as template in sharepoint online?

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow, template

I want to save a list workflow as template so that I may use it for another list, is it possible to do it in sharepoint online?

Comment: Are you need to save the workflow as template or the list itself ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two option to save/ backup your workflow as a template:

1. Save as Template.
2. Export to Visio.

**Save As Template Steps**

- from the above ribbon click on

[image]

- An informational dialog box appears to let you know the template has been saved to the Site Assets library.

**To restore from Save As Template**

- Go to asset library.

[image]

- Click Export File

[image]

- Go to your site > Click Site Actions and select Site Settings. > In the Web Design Galleries section >  click Solutions.
- Upload your exported WSP file > Activate it.
- Go back to Site Actions group, click Manage site features. > activate its feature.

[image]

For more details check [Ref](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj819316.aspx)

**Regarding Second option Export to visio.**

If you have Visio,from SharePoint designer ,  Try to export your workflow to Visio by following the mentioned steps below :

- Open SharePoint Designer.
- click on your completed List Workflow.
- Click on “Save” and “Publish” for the completed List Workflow.
- Next, click on “`Export to Visio`”. Save the file as `CompletedWorkflow.vwi` or any preferred name.

**To restore workflow template to the another site:**

- create a new “similar” list on the current site or on a new site collection.
- click on this new list and then click on “List Workflow” to create a new workflow for this new list.
- Please make sure that you do not add any workflow steps!
- Click on “Save” and “Publish” for this empty List Workflow.
- Then, click on “Export to Visio” and save this as EmptyWorkflow.vwi or any preferred name.
- Rename both the vwi files by adding “.zip” extension. The files should be CompletedWorkflow.vwi.zip and EmptyWorkflow.vwi.zip.
- The objective is to replace the “workflow.xoml.wfconfig.xml” file from the EmptyWorkflow.vwi.zip into the CompletedWorkflow.vwi.zip.
- It is likely that you cannot replace it directly. Copy the file out to the desktop and then copy the file into the other zipped folder.
- Remove the “.zip” extension from the CompletedWorkflow.vwi.
- With this, we have a working importable Visio List Workflow.
- Back in the SharePoint Designer , close all the workflow tabs.
- Click on the “Import from Visio” and select the CompletedWorkflow.vwi.

For more details check [Ref](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/wkng/2012/08/21/exporting-and-importing-sharepoint-designer-2010-list-workflow/)

**Note:**

I agree with Susan comment, both of the above methods are valid in case the another list has the same column names and parameters as the original list!

Comment: both of your methods are valid as long as column names and parameters are the same in the original list and the following ones?

Comment: Thank you @susan for your valuable comment, I totally agree, I have updated my answer to focus on your hint!