# Provision a library workflow from a template

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have a workflow associated with a library in a site, which is triggered automatically when a document is uploaded. I need to save this site as a template to provision new sites. However, as per my understanding, the provisioned sites will not have the same workflow associated with that particular library.

Is there any way of copying over the workflow associated with a library in a site template? If not, are there any workarounds available? (e.g.: having a site level template, or a workflow to copy the workflow)

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could save the workflow as template and then restore in target site.

[How to save list workflow as template in sharepoint online?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/212524/how-to-save-list-workflow-as-template-in-sharepoint-online)

Or, develop SharePoint integrated workflow, when you install the add-in in target site, the workflow will be deployed.

https://dev.office.com/patterns-and-practices-detail/1915