# How to publish issues list workflow to already exists subsites?

Tags: server, project

i have a list wf on Issues list, i have already saved the site as template so i don't worry about new subsites. but how can i apply the same wf to already exists subsites. am using sharepoint desiger 2013 and project server 2016.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Unfortunately,** There is no direct way to apply the newly created List workflow on the current site to the corresponding list in other subsites!!

**Workarounds**

1. [Export the created workflow](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/212524/how-to-save-list-workflow-as-template-in-sharepoint-online/212525#212525) and manually import it the corresponding list in other subsites!! I know it's a big headache but it considered a workaround solution.
2. Create a reusable workflow On the Issue Content type using Sharepoint Designer.

> **Note:** Reusable workflows are not created for a specific list or library but as the name suggests, they can be associated to any list
>   or library. Here we will be creating a reusable workflow on Content
>   Type (CT) and this CT is used by multiple list or libraries. This
>   allows our workflow to work for multiple list or libraries.

3. Develop a Code-Based Workflow and deploy it for all subsites as a feature.

---

For more details check

- [Create a Reusable Workflow on Content Type using SharePoint Designer 2013.](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/33157.sharepoint-2013-create-reusable-workflow-on-content-type-using-sharepoint-designer-2013.aspx)
- [How to save list workflow as template in sharepoint online?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/212524/how-to-save-list-workflow-as-template-in-sharepoint-online/212525#212525)

Comment: The best approach here would be to use Reusable Workflow here to avoid multiple times export and import and republishing. Totally agree with you Mohamed.

Comment: Thanks, @AnupamJagatdeo  appreciate your feedback :)